# Is there an open graph "person" object?

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

Let's say I had a "hugging" application that would let you say when you hugged one of your friends. What's the best way to set up the "person" object who receives the hugging action?

Ex: "hug" action -> "person" object - "George hugged Suzy"

The profile object seems like the best match, but doesn't seem to apply to facebook profile pages.

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm working on something similar where I need the facebook profile to be the object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is any suitable [built-in Open Graph object type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/) for a "person," and the [`profile` type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#external_profile) you found is for external profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one: http://ogp.me/#type_profile and http://ogp.me/ns/fb#profile_id the profile_id might do the trick.